# NullPointerException when using @JsonCreator and @JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, angularjs, jersey, jackson

I have a Java project for a RESTful API where I use Jackson/jersey to handle incoming JSON POST data that is being sent from an AngularJS enabled web application.

We are using jersey-json in version 1.8 (via Maven) because this is the recommended version in our company.

Everything worked well with the following class

```
public class POST_WorkitemInfo {
    public String workitem;
    public String workflow;
    public String taskname;
    public String force;
}
```

Even when we decided to use private members with an empty constructor and public setters it still worked fine.

But then we wanted to have the class immutable. After some research I found that I might be able to achieve this by using @JsonCreator together with @JsonProperty like this:

```
private final String workitem;
private final String workflow;
private final String taskname;
private final String force;

@JsonCreator
public POST_WorkitemInfo(@JsonProperty("workitem") String workitem, @JsonProperty("workflow") String workflow,
                         @JsonProperty("taskname") String taskname, @JsonProperty("force") String force) {
    this.workitem = workitem;
    this.workflow = workflow;
    this.taskname = taskname;
    this.force = force;
}
```

But now the call to the API fails with a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findAnnotation(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:860)
org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector._typeResolverFromXmlElements(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:318)
org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyTypeResolver(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:296)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findPropertyTypeResolver(AnnotationIntrospector.java:928)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findPropertyTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:502)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.resolveType(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:692)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.constructCreatorProperty(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:787)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerConstructors(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:590)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.findDeserializerCreators(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:524)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:393)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:370)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:359)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:281)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:261)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:119)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findTypedValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:140)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2197)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2112)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1004)
org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to add more annotations?

Comment: Ufff! 1.8 is an old one (but I'm sure you already know that). I was trying to take a look at the line that it failing at `grepcode`, hopefully it gives a hint (by looking at your code, no idea...) Can you provide the version you are using for the jar org.codehaus.jackson? By looking at jersey-json 1.8 pom, it points to 1.1, but there is no line 860 at `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` for that version.... Surely it is my mistake. Could you please post the version you are using?

Comment: Sorry I was on vacation in the meantime ... we are using version 1.7.1 of jackson

Comment: Hope you enjoyed your holidays! Ok, I don't find 1.7.1 in `grepcode`, the closest is 1.7.0 and indeed in that version your nullpointer makes a bit more sense, line 860 could have a null. Not *much* sense, though. Are you sure that your dependencies are congruent? Maybe you could post your pom.xml? It's a wild guess, but I would say that your version for jackson is too new for your version of jersey. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok I will check that ... but company architects will give us some time to test version 1.19 of jersey today. Maybe the problem will disappear

Comment: Then I would definitively check first with 1.19, before digging further into the problem... Good luck.

Comment: We will have to do some more tests ... just switching from jersey 1.8 to 1.19 was not possible because the REST API was not reachable any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We migrated to jersey version 1.19

After adding the dependency to jersey-servlet, everything worked fine, including the immutable classes with `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```